# Using ENUM types in functions

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a function defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.somefcn(
  _somevar enum_my_type
)
RETURNS integer AS
$body$
DECLARE
   ret_id INTEGER
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO mytable(somevar) VALUES (_somevar) RETURNING id INTO ret_id;
  RETURN ret_id;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

When I call this like this

```
SELECT somefcn('validenumitem');
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  column "somevar" is of type enum_my_type but expression is of type text

How should I update my function or call to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I had another, incorrect function as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.somefcn(
  _somevar text
)
...
```

Apparently, PostgreSQL took that one, because it fits better.